# Hash.new with block returns empty hash

Tags: ruby, hash

Why would this hash return empty? It's in my document model:

```
def li_hash
  li_hash = Hash.new do |share|
    share.comment "#{self.remove_html(self.components.first.body[0..300])}..."
    share.content do |c|
      c.title "#{self.title}"
      c.description "Read this"
      c.tag! "submitted-url", "#{root_url.gsub(/\/$/, '')}#{share_path(self.user.ftp, self)}"
      c.tag! "submitted-image-url", "#{root_url.gsub(/\/$/, '')}#{self.component.image_newsletter.path}"
    end
    share.visibility.code "anyone"
  end
end
```

I'm calling it from the console like so:

```
d = Document.find(328)
d.li_hash
```

And it just returns:

```
=> {}
```

The record is valid and all. Any thoughts? I'm trying to submit this hash to LinkedIn and it's obviously not working correctly.

Comment: What does ``share.visibility.code "anyone"`` do? It seems to be returning ``nil``...

Comment: It's setting a string to be `anyone`. It's not a variable or anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not actually setting anything in this code.  Also, I think you might be misunderstanding what passing a block to the hash does.  When you pass a block to the hash, what you can do is set a lambda that will be executed on every subsequent addition to the hash.

As the [documentation for `Hash.new`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Hash.html#method-c-new) states:

> If a block is specified, it will be called with the hash object and the key, and should return the default value. It is the block’s responsibility to store the value in the hash if required.

If you're trying to just set a bunch of parameters in a hash in a determinate way, you should just declare the hash explicitly like so:

```
{
  :comment => "#{self.remove_html(self.components.first.body[0..300])}...",
  :content => {
    :title => "#{self.title}",
    :description => "Read this",
  }
}
```

and then if you have any side effects (like the `tag!` method) do that seperately.

Comment: I've rewritten the method but it just throws me a bunch of `expecting keyword_end` errors. Will update the question. And thanks!

Comment: Hang on: commas? On the top level only?

Comment: Ah, got the formatting. `root_url` obviously won't work in the model, but yeah.

Answer (score 1):

`Hash.new` always returns an empty hash. The block you specified is just used to provide the default value when the hash is accessed with a key that doesn't already exist in the hash, per http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Hash.html#method-c-new, which states:

> If a block is specified, it will be called with the hash object and
>   the key, and should return the default value. It is the block’s
>   responsibility to store the value in the hash if required.

There will be nothing in the hash until you update the hash.